# How to get the first two data on group by group and sort by one column sequence on laravel

Tags: laravel, group-by, query-builder, laravel-query-builder

a16s table

```
id p_id u_id trust time
1   1   1      1    1
2   1   2      1    2
3   1   3      0    3
4   1   4      0    4
5   1   5      0    5
6   2   1      0    1
7   2   2      1    2
8   2   5      0    3
9   2   6      0    4
10  3   2      1    1
11  3   5      1    2
12  3   8      1    3
```

I want to get
the first two data on the trust group   by  the p_id group and shows data by the trust in turn

```
id  p_id    u_id    trust   time
1   1        1          1   1
2   1        2          1   2
4   1        4          0   4
5   1        5          0   5
7   2        2          1   2
6   2        1          0   1
8   2        5          0   3
10  3        2          1   1
11  3        5          1   2
```

I try the query

```
  $result = DB::table('a16s')
            ->select ('id','p_id','u_id','trust','time'))
            ->orderBy('time', 'desc')
            ->get()
            ->groupBy('p_id')
            ->get()
            ->groupBy('trust','desc')
            ->map(function ($deal) {
              return $deal->take(2);
              });


    echo '<pre>' ;
    print_r($result);
```

I got the error
Symfony \ Component \ Debug \ Exception \ FatalThrowableError (E_RECOVERABLE_ERROR)
Type error: Too few arguments to function Illuminate\Support\Collection::get(), 0 passed in D:\AppServ\www\comefour\app\Http\Controllers\CodoController.php on line 48 and at least 1 expected

Answer (score 0):

After your first ->get() the db query is converted to a collection.

A [collection get](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/collections#method-get) requires a key as an argument.

Put `->get()` right at the end of the builder query.

Like this:

```
$result = DB::table('a16s')
        ->select ('id','p_id','u_id','trust','time'))
        ->orderBy('time', 'desc')
        ->groupBy('p_id') // end of query
        ->get() // get the collection
        ->groupBy('trust','desc')
        ->map(function ($deal) {
          return $deal->take(2);
          });
```

Comment: I got the error ~Illuminate \ Database \ QueryException (42000)
SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1055 Expression #1 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'product.a16s.id' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by ...

Comment: With sql_mode=only_full_group_by you need to either add all selects to your group by or remove them from your select.

Comment: Are you mean  ->select (*)  ?

Comment: This is not related to your initial question. Here is some more info, hope it helps. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html